# Am I doing something wrong in my View that the flexDirection doesn't work?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the text to display to the right of the image, but for some reason flexDirection isn't working the way I am using it.

I've moved the flexDirection property around. Also have tried stuff other than View.

```
      <View
        style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
        style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: this.props.index % 2 == 0 ? '#420225' : '#69053e'
        }}
      >
      <Image
        source={{ uri: this.props.item.imageUrl }}
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, margin: 5 }}
      />
      <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{this.props.item.textContent} 
      </Text>
      </View>
```

I'm trying to get the Text to display to the right of the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your code a little. You should not have 2 styles for your View.

```
  <View
    style={{
     flex: 1,
     flexDirection: 'row' ,

    }}>
  <Image
    source={{ uri: "https://url.com" }}
    style={{ width: 100, height: 100, margin: 5 }}
  />
  <Text>something 
  </Text>
  </View>
```

Comment: they weren't hurting anyone! i left it that way after trying stuff because it's faster to allow yourself a little messiness while you're working the problem out.

Comment: I mean your problem was related to the two styles and if you check it now, you'll see the text is at the right side of the image. I checked it.  @Meowterspace

Comment: I see. Thank you very much<3